# How to pass additional arguments to callbacks and also access default parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Suppose I have this as an option to a jQuery widget:

```
    function oneFunc()
    {
     var myVar;

       //there is some widget calling
       $.widget("ui.combobox", $.ui.autocomplete, {
                options: {
                       source: function (request, response){////doing something with myVar, request and response}
                }
       });
    }
```

Now I want to separate out the `function (request, response)` using callback

So, I want something like this:

```
function oneFunc()
{
     var myVar;
     //there is some widget calling
        $.widget("ui.combobox", $.ui.autocomplete, {
                options: {
                       source: myCallBack
       });
}

function myCallBack(request, response){
//I can get request and response here by default but not myVar
//doing something with myVar, request and response
}
```

So, I can't access myVar. I have to pass it there. but how to do that?

**EDIT:**
I don't want to use global variables
`request`, `response` are default values that I can get in myCallBack anyway.

Better if anonymous function can be avoided.

Comment: `source: myCallBac` is not a valid JS statement.

Comment: `myCallBack anyway Better if anonymous function can be avoided.`....you already have an anonymous function ..here `function myCallBack(request, response){`

Comment: I guess it has a name- `myCallBack`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fcall)

```
function oneFunc(myCallback)
{
     this.myVar = 1;
    var request = "request";
    var response = "response"
     //there is some widget calling
     myCallback.apply(this,[request,response]);
}

function callback(request, response){
   console.log(request);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(this.myVar);
}

oneFunc(callback);
```

The above outputs

```
request
response
1
```

As you have delegated the `this` keyword to the callback method allowing it to access any variables declared in the original method.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/hFsCA/

Note the `apply` line can also be replaced with (Thanks @AlessandroVendruscolo)

```
myCallback.call(this,request,response);
```

Not that it makes too much difference - but for completeness!

So wrapping that back into your (now updated) example:

```
function oneFunc(callback)
{
   this.myVar = 1;
   var self = this;
   //there is some widget calling
   $.widget("ui.combobox", $.ui.autocomplete, {

            options: {
                 source: function (request, response){
                        callback.call(self,request,response);
                 }
            }
   });

}
```

Comment: I'd use `call`, because you're creating one array that is not really needed. `myCallback.call(this,request,response);`

Comment: `request` and `response` are not local to the function. they are only accessible after `source` is there. So `request` is undefined there.

Comment: Yeah! in that case I don't need to use `call` also. I can just send the variable. But I don't want to use anonymous function.

Comment: @soham.m17 - you're not making any sense. Of course you could just send the variable - I guess the advantage is that if you had 100 variables they would all be accessible in the `this` context. Not sure what you mean by "anonymous function". In any case, you asked a question and got an answer. If you don't like the answer think up a better question.

Comment: Well, the question states "how to pass additional arguments to callbacks..." I don't think your answer addresses that thing in particular. Anyway, it's a good solution avoiding the main course. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access `myVar` inside your separated callback function, I would make it explicit in the declaration:

```
function myCallBack(request, response, myVar) 
{
}
```

This makes it easier to keep track of when you see it in your code later on. Then, you write a proxy function like this:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    return myCallBack.call(this, request, response, myVar);
}
```

If you want a more complex scope or `myVar` needs to be changed in both scopes, you need an object:

```
var myScope = {
    myVar: null
};

// ...

source: function(request, response) {
    return myCallBack.call(this, request, response, myScope);
}
```

Then, inside the callback:

```
function myCallBack(request, response, myScope) 
{
    // use myVar as myScope.myVar
}
```

Comment: Actually it would be better if I can pass the argument to the callback not using any anonymous function. Although this thing works. But I don't want to use anonymous function.
What I am thinking is that we can just place `myCallBack` inside `oneFunc()` also. That also solves the problem. As `myVar` then would be in scope of `myCallBack` also.
But again, that's not elegant code.

Comment: @soham.m17 This is starting to sound like an XY problem; you don't like to use anonymous functions, but obviously the state inside `oneFunc()` must be somehow transferred. What exactly does `myVar` contain, what are you writing?

Comment: It's a simple string. That is modified in `myCallBack`.

Comment: No, `myVar` is sent to `myCallBack` and reused in `oneFunc()` again. 
I think I am sounding ambiguous.
I simply want to use `call backs` with additional parameter capability.

Comment: @soham.m17 Well, then you need anonymous functions to gather the scope used for your callback, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't if jQuery is internally using any anonymous function or not. But I solved it by this:

```
function oneFunc()
{
     var myVar;
     //there is some widget calling
        $.widget("ui.combobox", $.ui.autocomplete, {
                options: {
                       source: $.proxy(myCallBack, this, myVar)
       });
}

function myCallBack(myVar, request, response){
//I can access myVar, request and response
//doing something with myVar, request and response
}
```

Other experienced people can comment on this, I guess.